# equivalent of com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver in onesignal 4 for the AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-manifest, onesignal

I'm trying to upgrade from `'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.2'` to `'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'` but I can't find the equivalent of `com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver` in the documentation for `com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]`

here is the documentation that I use for the upgrade: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-13-push-notification-developer-update-guide

the code below is a piece of code from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for `com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.2` and I want to replace it with its equivalent for `com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]`

```
        <receiver
        android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <!-- High priority so OneSignal payloads can be filtered from other GCM receivers if filterOtherGCMReceivers is enabled. -->
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver` was replaced with `com.onesignal.FCMBroadcastReceiver` in the 4.0.0 release of the OneSignal SDK.

`FCMBroadcastReceiver` is just an implementation detail of OneSignal-Android-SDK, there is no need to add this to your own `AndroidManifest.xml` as the SDK already includes it for you:
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/4.8.6/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/src/release/AndroidManifest.xml#L10-L19